Catch2 Test failure crashes test suite when compiled with Emscripten
I have a c++ project that I am compiling to WebAssembly via Emscripten. I would like to use Catch2 for running tests, but I notice that when a test fails, rather than the test suite finishing with a log of which test(s) failed, the executable itself crashes with a Catch::TestFailureException
Here is a reproduction of my test suite that gives the error
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>

TEST_CASE("Foo","Bar") {
    REQUIRE(1 == 2); // I expect this to fail
}

Here is my main app CMakeTests.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(HelloEmscripten)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

Include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
  Catch2
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
  GIT_TAG        v3.4.0 # or a later release
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${catch2_SOURCE_DIR}/extras)

add_subdirectory(test)

And here is the CMakeLists.txt file for the test directory
add_executable(unit_tests test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(unit_tests PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2WithMain)

include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(unit_tests)

if(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Emscripten")
    target_link_options(unit_tests PRIVATE -fexceptions)
    target_compile_options(unit_tests PRIVATE -fexceptions)
endif()

I build the code, and then run node ./test/unit_tests
Then I see the following output
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
unit_tests is a Catch2 v3.4.0 host application.
Run with -? for options

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Foo
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
~/workshop/cpp/tutorials/emscripten/source/test/test.cpp:3
...............................................................................

~/workshop/cpp/tutorials/emscripten/source/test/test.cpp:4: FAILED:
  REQUIRE( 1 == 2 )

~/workshop/cpp/tutorials/emscripten/build/test/unit_tests.js:1242
      exceptionLast = new CppException(ptr);
                      ^

Catch::TestFailureException
    at ___cxa_throw (~/workshop/cpp/tutorials/emscripten/build/test/unit_tests.js:1242:23)
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[6608]:0xcf671
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[478]:0xdc52
    at invoke_vi (~/workshop/cpp/tutorials/emscripten/build/test/unit_tests.js:4646:29)
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[56]:0x4c1f
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[6637]:0xd0386
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[5043]:0x9c8c1
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[4946]:0x988ef
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[4942]:0x98601
    at wasm://wasm/005ded6e:wasm-function[4938]:0x97c78 {
  excPtr: 136168
}

Does anyone know what the issue is here?
Personal observations:

Naturally, this does error does not happen if I build the code without emscripten and then run ./test/unit_test
Tests run to completion as long as none of them fail.
I'm currently setting EM exception handling via target_xxx_options and -fexceptions, but the issue persists if I use fwasm-exceptions or set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0")

